# Android - How can I save longer TTS wavefiles from synthesizeToFile?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Using the typical method for rendering a wav file from TTS,

```
         HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
         myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, translatedtexttodisplay);
         tts.synthesizeToFile(translatedtexttodisplay, myHashRender, destFileName);
```

I usually get 44 byte files with no data.  I do get viable files (in kilobytes) from single-word TTS outputs.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you setting an `OnUtteranceProgressListener` ? Without it, sometimes TTS can misbehave. You also might be trying to open the file before it has finished writing.

Comment: I am surprised that 701 people have viewed this thread, and nobody has chosen to comment. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are following this thread, the answer is to 
setOnUtteranceProgressListener just before the call to synthesize the WAV; then put all the actual copying to file in the onDone() method of your listener.  It then won't write out the file prematurely, truncating it badly.

It's pretty long and ugly to write out, but the important parts are here:

```
         HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();           
         myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "id");
         tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new TtsUtteranceListener());
         tts.synthesizeToFile(translatedtexttodisplay, myHashRender, destFileName);
```

Then,

```
public class TtsUtteranceListener extends UtteranceProgressListener {

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

        [stuff to save the file appropriately]
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        Log.d("TtsUtteranceListener", "utterance Start: " + utteranceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
        Log.d("TtsUtteranceListener", "utterance Error: " + utteranceId);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I used a

```
        // wait here for file to be created 
         try {
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         showToast("Oops! Exception!");
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

to be sure.  Importantly, this is what seems to have done the trick.